# Newton's Fractal optimising

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

recently I wrote a program to graph Newton's Fractal, being able to move the roots of the equation around. However, the execution is very slow, and I am considering switching to a faster language. Is it possible to speed up the implementation more that I have or is it unfeasible? I have though about Pypy but it does not support cython. Is my use of numpy correct or can it be further optimised?

````
import cython
import numpy as np
# cimport numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
# cimport matplotlib.plt as plt

# plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
# plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

min, max = -2, 2
step = 0.01

def cmp(x,y):
    return x + 1j * y

def faster_polyval(p, x):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.complex128)
    for i, v in enumerate(p):
        y *= x
        y += v
    return y

def newton(val, it, roots):
    eq = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots(roots)
    der = np.polyder(eq)
    li = 0
    still_going = np.zeros(val.shape)
    for i in range(it):
        li = val
        # r = polyval_factory(eq)
        # k = polyval_factory(der)
        # val = val - np.polyval(eq,val)/np.polyval(der,val)
        # val = val - r(val)/k(val)
        val = val-faster_polyval(eq,val)/faster_polyval(der,val)
        converged = np.invert(abs(val-li) < 0.00000001)
        still_going[converged] = i
    return still_going

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

a = np.arange(min,max+step,step)
b = np.arange(min,max+step,step)
x, y = np.meshgrid(a, b)

roots = [cmp(1,0), cmp(-0.5,math.sqrt(3)/2),cmp(-0.5,-math.sqrt(3)/2)]
# eq = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fromroots(roots)
# der = eq.deriv()

ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')

ax_slider = plt.axes([0.20, 0.01, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='yellow')
slider = Slider(ax_slider, 'Root 1 real part', valmin=-2, valmax=2, valinit = roots[0].real)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.20, 0.04, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='yellow')
slider1 = Slider(ax_slider, 'Root 1 img part', valmin=-2, valmax=2, valinit = roots[0].imag)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.20, 0.07, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='yellow')
slider2 = Slider(ax_slider, 'Root 2 real part', valmin=-2, valmax=2, valinit = roots[1].real)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.20, 0.10, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='yellow')
slider3 = Slider(ax_slider, 'Root 2 img part', valmin=-2, valmax=2, valinit = roots[1].imag)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.20, 0.13, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='yellow')
slider4 = Slider(ax_slider, 'Root 3 real part', valmin=-2, valmax=2, valinit = roots[2].real)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.20, 0.16, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='yellow')
slider5 = Slider(ax_slider, 'Root 3 img part', valmin=-2, valmax=2, valinit = roots[2].imag)

def update(val):
    roots[0] = cmp(val,roots[0].imag)
    ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def update1(val):
    roots[0] = cmp(roots[0].real, val)
    ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def update2(val):
    roots[1] = cmp(val,roots[1].imag)
    ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def update3(val):
    roots[1] = cmp(roots[1].real,val)
    ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def update4(val):
    roots[2] = cmp(val,roots[2].imag)
    ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def update5(val):
    roots[2] = cmp(roots[2].real, val)
    ax.imshow(newton(cmp(x,y), 15, roots), cmap = 'inferno')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider.on_changed(update)
slider1.on_changed(update1)
slider2.on_changed(update2) 
slider3.on_changed(update3)
slider4.on_changed(update4)
slider5.on_changed(update5)
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the involved math, nor with Cython. However, I can tell you this about matplotlib. Every time you use `ax.imshow()` a new image will be created and put above the existing stack of images. All images will be rendered at each update, which will increasingly slow down the updates. What you need to do is to add `ax.images.clear()` inside each update function, before executing `ax.imshow`.

Still, you probably need to look for a faster newton implementation, or cythonize the code.